# Access variables declared a component from a RxJS subscribe() function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, arrow-functions

I am able to use `this.variable` to access variables in any part of the component, except inside RxJS functions like `subscribe()` or `catch()`.

In the example below, I want to print a message after running a process:

```typescript
import {Component, View} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'navigator'
})
@View({
    template: './app.component.html',
    styles: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    message: string;

    constructor() {
        this.message = 'success';
    }

    doSomething() {
        runTheProcess()
        .subscribe(function(location) {
            console.log(this.message);
        });
    }
}
```

When I run `doSomething()`, I get **undefined**. This scenario can be solved using a local variable:

```typescript
import {Component, View} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'navigator'
})
@View({
    template: './app.component.html',
    styles: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    message: string;

    constructor() {
        this.message = 'success';
    }

    doSomething() {

        // assign it to a local variable
        let message = this.message;

        runTheProcess()
        .subscribe(function(location) {
            console.log(message);
        });
    }
}
```

I suppose this is related to the `this`, however, why I can't access the `this.message` inside the `subscribe()`?

Comment: arrow functions https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/arrow-functions.html

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This has nothing to do with rx or angular, and everything to do with Javascript and Typescript.

I assume you're familiar with the semantics of `this` in the context of function invocations in Javascript (if not, there are [no shortage of explanations online](http://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/11/understanding-javascript-function-invocation-and-this/)) - those semantics apply in the first snippet, of course, and that's the only reason `this.message` is undefined inside `subscribe()`there. That's just Javascript.

Since we're talking about Typescript: 
[Arrow functions](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/arrow-functions.html) are a Typescript construct intended (in part) to sidestep the awkwardness of these semantics by lexically capturing the meaning of `this`, meaning that `this` inside an arrow function === `this` from the outer context.

So, if you replace:

```
.subscribe(function(location) {
        //this != this from outer context 
        console.log(this.message); //prints 'undefined'
    });
```

by:

```
.subscribe((location) => {
     //this == this from the outer context 
        console.log(this.message); //prints 'success'
    });
```

You'll get your expected result.

Comment: I know this is an old question - but when I follow your answer and run my application in google chrome I get a page crash - memory error.. any idea?

Comment: Is there any quick solution to reference the outer 'this' in the fat arrow function?

Comment: @etlds, if you are talking about referencing "this" while debugging, then you can watch for _this

Otherwise, internally, the "this" refers to the outside context (when used in arrow function)

Comment: Thanks, This is very useful!

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to @drewmoore's answer, if you wish to have external functions you can do:

```
 .subscribe((location) => dataHandler(location), (error) => errorHandler(error));

 ....

 const dataHandler = (location) => {
     ...
 }
```

By externalising the `errorHandler` function, it can be used in multiple places (ie. subscriptions).  By having as (fat) arrow functions your code will capture the 'this' context (as discussed in @Drewmoore's answer).

What is lacking is the ability to write the following and have handled like an arrow function.  The following works and passes the argument implicitly.  Unfortunately AFAIK you cannot capture the `this` context (perhaps use `bind` to achieve this, though that makes the code more verbose overall).

```
 .subscribe(dataHandler, errorHandler);
```

This is soooo succinct!  But alas won't work if the context is required.