# Setting form input value from component in angular 2

Tags: javascript, forms, angular

I have following input inside a form:

```
<form [ngFormModel]="newListingForm" (ngSubmit)="submitListing(newListingForm.value)">

<input type="text" placeholder="00.000" #mapLatitudeInput="ngForm" [ngFormControl]="newListingForm.controls['mapLatitudeInput']">

</form>
```

I need to update its value when I'm dragging map around, so from related component that looks like this:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {FORM_DIRECTIVES, FormBuilder, ControlGroup, Validators} from 'angular2/common';

@Component({
  templateUrl : 'app/components/new-listing/new-listing.html',
  directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES]
})

export class NewListingComponent {

  //Costructor
  constructor(
    fb: FormBuilder
  ){

    //New Listing Form
    this.newListingForm = fb.group({
      'mapLatitudeInput': ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }

  //Google maps
  loadMap(latitude, longitude) {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('listing-map'), {
      center: {lat: latitude, lng: longitude},
      zoom: 18,
      scrollwheel: false,
      mapTypeControl: false,
      streetViewControl: false
    });

    //Update coordinates on map drag
    map.addListener('drag', function(event) {

      //ISSUE HERE
      this.newListingForm.controls.mapLatitudeInput.value = map.getCenter().lat()

      //console.log(map.getCenter().lat());
      //console.log(map.getCenter().lng());
    });
  }

  //TODO Form submission
  submitListing(value: string): void {
    console.log("Form Submited");
  }

  //Log error
  logError(err) {
   console.error('Error: ' + err);
  }

}
```

What I thought would be a correct way is where `//ISSUE HERE` comment is, but that throws an undefined error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unable to get component variables inside a RxJS subscribe() function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34647449/unable-to-get-component-variables-inside-a-rxjs-subscribe-function)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use an arrow function for your drag callback:

```
map.addListener('drag', (event) => {
  this.newListingForm.controls.mapLatitudeInput.value
                                  = map.getCenter().lat()
});
```

In this case, the `this` keywork will be the instance of the component itself.

Perhaps you could leverage the `ngModel` directive to set the value of your input instead of the control. It allows to use two way binding.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="00.000"
       #mapLatitudeInput="ngForm"
       [ngFormControl]="newListingForm.controls['mapLatitudeInput']"
       [(ngModel)]="mapCoordinates.latitude">
```

The `mapCoordinates` object would be an attribute of your component with two fields: `longitude` and `latitude`.

```
@Component({
  templateUrl : 'app/components/new-listing/new-listing.html',
  directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class NewListingComponent {
  constructor() {
    this.mapCoordinates = {
      longitude: 0, latitude: 0
    };
  }
}
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: I'm getting following error now: Cannot set property value of #<AbstractControl> which has only a getter

Comment: And within my text editor following error: Property 'mapLatitudeInput' does not exist on type '{ [key: string]: AbstractControl; }'

Comment: I think that you should leverage the `ngModel` directive... I updated my answer ;-)

Comment: I tried using ngModel before for this, but didn't figure it out. How do I bind mapCoordinates inside a component? I have tried puting mapCoordinates: Object; under my class export line and accessing it like this.mapCoordinates.latitude, but this doesn't seem to work

Comment: I updated my answer. In fact, you simply need to initialize the component attribute... Then your input is linked on it using `[(ngModel)]` with two way binding.

Comment: Adding it this way prompts an error: ``` Property mapLatitudeModel does not exist on type 'NewListingComponent' ``` I added [(ngModel)]="mapLatitudeModel" to appropriate input

Comment: Here is a plunkr showing you how to use this: https://plnkr.co/edit/0l9KxsuT9fLV3A64Sw4X?p=preview.

Comment: It seems that it just doesn't work inside that drag function. Thank you for clearing this out. I'll keep digging into the issue