# Cannot Access Component Variables in Subscribe when using chrome inspector

Tags: angular, angular2-components

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34647449/unable-to-get-component-variables-inside-a-rxjs-subscribe-function) but I already seem to have the selected answer. I have the following...

```
import {Component, OnDestroy} from '@angular/core';
import {MdIconRegistry} from "@angular2-material/icon/icon-registry";
import {MD_ICON_DIRECTIVES} from "@angular2-material/icon/icon";
import {ShowcaseCardComponent} from "./showcase-card/showcase-card.component";
import { WheelService } from "../../wheel/wheel.service";
@Component({
    selector: 'jg-showcase',
    template: String(require('./showcase.component.pug')),
    styles: [String(require('./showcase.component.styl'))],
    directives: [MD_ICON_DIRECTIVES, ShowcaseCardComponent],
    viewProviders: [MdIconRegistry]
})
export class ShowcaseComponent implements OnDestroy{
    currentCard: number = 0;
    subscription: any;
    cards = [
        {
            number: 0,
            color: "blue",
            content: "<h1>Card1</h1>"
        },
        {
            number: 1,
            content: "<h1>Card2</h1>"
        }
    ];
    constructor(wheelService: WheelService){
        this.subscription = wheelService.wheelEmitter.subscribe((data: any) => {
           if(data.direction > 0 && this.currentCard !== this.cards.length){
               this.currentCard++;
           }
           else if(this.currentCard){
               this.currentCard--;
           }
           console.log("Current Card "+this.currentCard);
        })
    };
    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.subscription.dispose();
    };
}
```

problem is that `this` is undefined in the inspector but I see the proper console.log...

```
Current Card 1
Current Card 2
```

Why is the console saying it is undefined

```
this.currentCard
VM10154:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'currentCard' of undefined(…)
```

Comment: The issue you are observing is only in chrome inspector ? If that is true then it is to do with how arrow function of TS and function.bind works in JS. Inspector may not able to get correct this

Comment: The last quote shows inspector not seeing the variable, even thought the code works.

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with how [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) are implement in TS. 
`this` in arrow function is lexically inferred so it more in line with below code

```
function Person() {
  var self = this; // Some choose `that` instead of `self`. 
                   // Choose one and be consistent.
  self.age = 0;

  setInterval(function growUp() {
    // The callback refers to the `self` variable of which
    // the value is the expected object.
    self.age++;
  }, 1000);
}
```

So inside the arrow function it is not actually `this` but a context closer `self`.  This may not be actual implementation but much closer to give you understanding of what is happening.

Now in Inspector when you type this it is outside the closer/ arrow function so will not get the correct context for this hence Inspector will show you either `undefined` or `window` or some `global object`

This should explain why your code is working but Inspector is not giving you expected value.

**Protip** see your transpiled JS how  your arrow function is transforming.

Comment: So you are essentially saying the arrow function is running in a different context than the inspector? Am I understanding this properly?

Comment: exactly. Arrow function has correct context whereas inspector does not